# Facebook event subscriber: FB.event does not appear to work on Ipdas

Tags: facebook, ipad, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

```js
FB.Event.subscribe('egde.create', function(response) {
 alert('can you see me on an ipad??');
 });
```

Has anyone else had trouble getting code like this to work on ipads? I am trying to react to a Facebook 'like' event. And this exact code works everywhere except on Ipads.
Does anyone know a workaround for this?